# Python - Multiprocessing via Different IPython Consols

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a more general beginners question about multiprocessing in Python (please forgive me if I'm utterly wrong in the following). Let's assume I launch two ore more Ipython consols in parallel and run some independent functions/scripts via those consols, does that meant these tasks are performed on multiple cores (one core per task)? If yes, would it be better to collect the tasks in a "main module" and use the `multiprocessing` library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference between starting processes in two terminals or using multiprocessing:

- when you open two python consoles you have two processes with their pid
- when you run two multiprocessing processes they are `fork`ed (on Linux) or started as separate python instance (Windows) and thus run as independent processes.

What the OS does with this processes is beyond your control. If both processes use a lot of CPU resources and there is only little other processes they will be spread across cores.